# Sitecore 8.1 copying bucket item ends up by copying to same parent

Tags: sitecore-client, content-editor

Issue with the item copy functionality.

When I try to copy any bucket item to another item (bucket or non bucket item) on selection of item in content tree, it works fine. But when the same has been attempted by mentioning the path of destination folder, in path field of “Copy item to dialog box”, it creates a copy in the same parent.

Please follow below mentioned steps to recreate the scenario mentioned above.

- Right click on the item to be copied.
- EDIT the path field with desired destination field and click copy
  button.
- Item is created under the same parent though path mentioned in the
  Path field was different

Note: If the case is like, we have to select item in the content tree, and mentioning the path in the path field is of no use. Can I get a patch where path field is disabled?